# Database deadlock when migrating from Entity Framework 5 to Entity Framework 6 inside a transaction

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

We have a database that has been created with Entity Framework 5 (and SQL Server 2008 R2) using code first migrations. If we then attempt to upgrade to Entity Framework 6.1.0 then it hangs while migrating the database until there is a transaction timeout.

We do the migrations inside of a transaction to make sure that we can roll-back the changes if anything goes wrong (our migration app also makes some changes using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server). If instead we don't use a transaction then the migration succeeds.

We have tracked the point where it hangs to some code that queries the migration history table outside of the ambient transaction (uses TransactionScopeOption.Suppress for this) in HistoryRepository.GetPendingMigrations(), line 299.

We have been able to reproduce this with a minimal test app. Something like:

- Create a database using Entity Framework 5 code first migrations.
- Upgrade to Entity Framework 6.1.0 and add a migration.
- Attempt to run the migration inside a transaction and the application will hang, e.g.

`using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
    using (var ctx = new DemoContext())
    {
        Console.Write(ctx.Entities.Any());
        ts.Complete();
    }`

We've filed a [bug](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2319) on codeplex but as yet have no feedback :(

**EDIT:**

After further investigation of the EF code we can't see how this can be avoided. Specifically, EF creates a new MigrationsHistory table inside the wrapping transaction, but tries to access it outside the transaction (using TransactionScopeOption.Suppress). As the new table is locked this causes a database deadlock, and even if it didn't the changes inside the transaction wouldn't be visible at the isolation level we use.

Comment: Have you tried changing the timeout on the TransactionScope?

Comment: Yes. Also, the migration completes in seconds if there is no wrapping transaction; whereas it stalls for at least 30 minutes before failing if there is a wrapping transaction. Once stalled, there is - according to SQL Server Profiler - no further access to the database.